# Amazon Cognito: Enforcing password expiration policy

Tags: amazon-cognito

Is there a way to enforce password expiration policy on users in Amazon Cognito user pools?

Answer (score 18):

It doesn't look like expiration is built into the [password policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-policies.html). You could track password expiration by adding a `passwordUpdatedAt` field and manually updating that attribute on user sign up and on `changePassword`. Then you could schedule something that queries users with expired passwords and call [AdminResetUserPassword](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminResetUserPassword.html) for those users. It would be somewhat more reliable if AWS published Cognito Userpoool User events like `changePassword` or just baked it into the service.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I hoped I wouldn't have to do. I keep bumping into these cases where I have to "manually" manage the identity state, making Cognito appear more like a limited DB table than a IdP solution.

Comment: Cognito dev here: Unfortunately this is the best way to accomplish this. I can take this as a +1 to prioritizing handling password expiry out of box, though.

Comment: Hi @eddywashere when i tried to use `AdminResetUserPassword` it is throwing an exception saying It is not a function. I used it like this `await Auth.AdminResetUserPassword(this.state.email);` where `Auth` has `PoolID`.

Comment: For others, it looks like adminResetUserPassword and the cognito library in general has moved to the aws-sdk (not to be confused with the aws-amplify lib). Link to usage https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminResetUserPassword-property

Comment: Anyone else finding the issue is that this sends us down the route to show the forgot password workflow. Cognito allows the user to select the previous password so whats the point?

Comment: @JeffBailey has this feature been implemented?