# how to set expiration of password in aws-cognito with node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito

I am trying to do something like -

```
  All user passwords should expire every 90 days.
  Users should be forced to reset their expired passwords upon login to share with last password.
```

anybody have any idea, how to do it in aws-cognito with nodejs ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: please don't spam unrelated tags

Answer (score 0):

Cognito does not have an option for password expiration, but you can add the custom user attribute "custom:passwordUpdateDate" where you are going to check when the password was updated and use AdminResetUserPassword.  [Amazon Cognito: Enforcing password expiration policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44895207/amazon-cognito-enforcing-password-expiration-policy)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have more questions,,
How do I get updated date of password? Is it right  to use 'UserLastModifiedDate'?
I tried it, but error is displayed in console.

Comment: you should not use UserLastModifiedDate, create a custom field
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/aws-amplify-adds-support-for-custom-attributes-in-amazon-cognito-user-pools/

Answer (score 0):

you can use api of aws-cognito user:

> aws cognito-idp admin-get-user --user-pool-id us-east-1poolID --username youUser name or email --profile default

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region:'us-east-1'});
var http = require('http')

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

/*Initializing CognitoIdentityServiceProvider from AWS SDK JS*/
var RecivedData = {}

// var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {   //create web server
//     if (req.url == '/') { //check the URL of the current request
        
        
    
//     }
// }
// )
const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
    apiVersion: "2016-04-18",
});



const USERPOOLID = "you-pool id here";


const Check = async (event, context) => {
    const EMAIL = "your email or user name ";
    const cognitoParams = {
        UserPoolId: USERPOOLID,
        Username: EMAIL
    };

    let response = await cognito.adminGetUser(cognitoParams).promise();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
    RecivedData = {...RecivedData,response}
    console.log(RecivedData)
}
(async ()=>{Check();})();
app.get('/' , (req,res)=>{
    // Server will send resonse
    res.send(RecivedData); 
 })
   
 // Server setup
 app.listen(4000 , ()=>{
     console.log("server running 4000");
 });
```

you will response in response you will get like this

```js
{
  response: {
    Username: 'something',
    UserAttributes: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    UserCreateDate: 2022-03-21T13:17:05.246Z,
    UserLastModifiedDate: 2022-03-21T13:42:09.303Z,
    Enabled: true,
    UserStatus: 'CONFIRMED'
  }
}
```

here you see UserLastModifiedDate using this you can set password expiry of the aws-cognito user.
hope this will help you